# How to determine command location?

Tags: java, command-line

I need to use [keytool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/keytool.html) and I want to use possible newest version. I have on my Ubuntu oracle jdk, and OpenJDK.

```
~$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_25-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)
```

keytool command is located in two places:

```
~$ type -a keytool
keytool is /usr/bin/keytool
keytool is /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_25/bin/keytool
~$ file /usr/bin/keytool
/usr/bin/keytool: symbolic link to /etc/alternatives/keytool
~$ file /etc/alternatives/keytool
/etc/alternatives/keytool: symbolic link to /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/keytool
```

How do I know if I use `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/keytool` or `/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_25/bin/keytool` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `which` instead.

```
$ which keytool
/usr/bin/keytool
```

Answer (score 3):

or you can use `whereis`, like:

```
whereis keytool
```

for extended information including `which` output at first place.

Answer (score 3):

If the command is an managed by alternatives, you may want to use:

```
update-alternatives --list keytool
```

That will output all registered alternatives. This is not a simple search of `bin` directories. See example:

```
update-alternatives --list vi
```